# How to use Win32 classes like Win32_Printer?

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I have to use Win32 classes like `Win32_PrintJob`, `Win32_Printer` etc in C#.net.

I am not getting which namespace I should import to use Win32 classes in My c#.net application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to the WMI from C# (or .Net) you must import the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  namespace. Also if you are new using the WMI try a tool like the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) which can help you to create a C# snippet to access the WMI.

Try this sample code, created by the tool.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                

                if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                {
                    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                    Conn.Username  = "";
                    Conn.Password  = "";
                    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
                }
                else
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Document",WmiObject["Document"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);// String

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are WMI classes, so you will need to use `System.Management` namespace.

Here is a great article about printers: [Managing Printers Programatically using C# and WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80680/Managing-Printers-Programatically-using-C-and-WMI)

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't marked an answer yet, probably you're looking for the other answers that give you the .NET framework namespace `System.Management`.

However, it *is* possible that you've been reading the WMI documentation and you're coming from that perspective. One of the fundamental concepts is the **WMI namespace**, which of course is something completely different than the .NET namespace. So here's a completely different answer just in case...

---

The #1 WMI namespace you're ever likely to need is `root\cimv2`. Only if you're digging deep you might use `root\subscription` or some namespace chosen by a company who decided to put their own WMI provider someplace 'special'.

In general when you want to connect to a WMI namespace, it comes after the computer name , e.g. `\\<computer>\root\cimv2`. When connecting locally the computer can be omitted, so you'd put just the namespace path, e.g. `root\cimv2`

In .NET, you specify the WMI namespace by using it in the string to build a `ManagementPath`, or implicitly in the string you pass to the `ManagementScope` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are sure such objects implemented in .NET, so you not need to use those objects.
If you must to work against winapi directly, you can create a struct that contains everything contained in winapi structs (they are structs, not classes).

Some notes:
Keep the exact order and type of all members.
Represent handles (such as HWND etc.) with `System.IntPtr`.
If you need to pass the size of the struct, use `Marshal.SizeOf()`.
You can also add the `[StructLayout]` attribute, where you can specify the charset and other important properties.
The namespace `System.Runtime.InteropServices` has some common winapi structs.

Comment: +0 Reasonable, but way to generic answer to relaively scoped question.